# GKE - exposing Grafana externally not working using GCP Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, grafana, kubernetes-ingress

I've Prometheus/Grafana enabled on GKE (in namespace - monitoring)

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:ingress-ns karanalang$ kc get svc -n monitoring
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
grafana               ClusterIP      10.80.9.14    <none>           3000/TCP         7d4h
prometheus-operated   ClusterIP      None          <none>           9090/TCP         7d4h
prometheus-operator   ClusterIP      None          <none>           8080/TCP         7d4h
```

I'm trying to expose Grafana using Ingress, below is the Ingress description,
the path is '/grafana'

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:ingress-ns karanalang$ kc describe ingress ingress-grafana -n monitoring
Name:             ingress-grafana
Namespace:        monitoring
Address:          34.117.119.113
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.76.0.8:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /grafana   grafana:3000 (10.76.0.5:3000)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {"k8s-be-31823--45a575f79c8f25d8":"HEALTHY","k8s1-45a575f7-monitoring-grafana-3000-2fa5518a":"HEALTHY"}
              ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s2-fr-tkept4vc-monitoring-ingress-grafana-y11p7u0i
              ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s2-tp-tkept4vc-monitoring-ingress-grafana-y11p7u0i
              ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-tkept4vc-monitoring-ingress-grafana-y11p7u0i
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                  From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync       23m                  loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-tkept4vc-monitoring-ingress-grafana-y11p7u0i" created
  Normal  Sync       23m                  loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-tkept4vc-monitoring-ingress-grafana-y11p7u0i" created
  Normal  Sync       23m                  loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fr-tkept4vc-monitoring-ingress-grafana-y11p7u0i" created
  Normal  IPChanged  23m                  loadbalancer-controller  IP is now 34.117.119.113
  Normal  Sync       5m12s (x7 over 23m)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

when i do a curl /grafana, it shows that login is found
However - when i use the same on the browser, it gives '404 Not Found'

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:ingress-ns karanalang$ curl 34.117.119.113/grafana
<a href="/login">Found</a>.
```

what needs to be done to debug/fix this ?

tia!

[image: grafana UI not coming up]

Comment: check your browser console and see if file are facing issue or any path loading issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description provided for your `ingress-grafana` Ingress resource, it is a normal behavior. You only use `/grafana` path in the rules. But the screenshot shows a redirect to the `/login` page. And since you don't have other rules, you get this message.

To solve this problem, you can change path in the `ingress-grafana` Ingress resource to `/*` as shown below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: grafana
            port:
              number: 3000
```

This will allow to use redirections for the Grafana service.

Comment: @Andrew Skorkin - Grafana works fine if i give path as "/", however - i need to make it accessible on path <hostname>/grafana .. how do i do that ? any ideas ?

Comment: from what i understand, the grafana yaml (config needs to be changed) .. however, i'm not yet clear on what the changes are

Comment: @Andrew Skorkin - while the browser shows -> http://<hostname>/login .. i pasted http://<hostname>/grafana on the browser, it got converted to http://<hostname>/login

Comment: Yes that's right. I mentioned about redirect. That is why I proposed using the `path: /*` Have you tried Ingress from my answer?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin - yes, that works fine .. however, my requirement is to have a single domain name, and do path based routing i.e. http://domain/grafana or http://domain/prometheus

Comment: Sorry, but your question is only about Grafana. If you want something different, please create a new question.